# Resetting MySite to site definition

Tags: sharepoint-online

We are using Sharepoint Online, and I would like to reset My Site of one user to site definition.
I have doubts and since Online has limited access to the Sharepoint server farm, I'd like to double-check before I destroy something valuable.

1.All my customizations will be deleted?
2.Since mySites are interconnected, will other users be affected as well?
3. I know that if you delete the MySite, you are facing a lot of issues with Sharepoint and basically have to contact the farm admins (Microsoft) to restore - will reset invoke similar behaviour?

Thanks in advance

Comment: To answer your second question, each user's My Site is a site in the My Site site collection.  Resetting one user's site to site definition affects only that site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Yes All customization will be deleted.  it removes any customization and reverts the file back to the version originally deployed via the Site Definition. Customized pages are stored in the Content Database (a copy with changes) and are called unghosted. When you reset, the customized copy gets deleted and the version on the file system (the Site Definition version) is used

2) every MySite is an independent Site collection, so reset one MYSite will not impact to other.

3) if you delete MySite either Tenant Administrator or from MSFT Support will recover it(if you need the data back). But you dont want data back then you can create new Mysite for the user.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer. Emboldened, I went ahead and did it, picking the option: reset all the sites (you can choose either one site or all). Nothing happened. On purpose I waited till today to see if maybe there's some delay. All site's customizations, added libraries, folders, files, changes in colour and layout, in-line text remained the same. Profile picture and newsfeed posts  didn't disappear either although I didn't expect them to. I tested on another site: nothing happened again. Is it an issue and I should contact MFST Support?

Comment: Just to finish the thread: the lack of reaction from "Reset site to site definition" is a bug and I have contacted MFST Support about it